# How to read multiple pages using pdfbox

Tags: nlp, pdfbox

I want to read a Sinhala eBook using PDF box. I can read English one page PDF using PDF box. what I want is read multiple pages at once and store them

Comment: What do you mean by *"read"*? Do you mean *extract the text content*? Or do you mean *render as bitmap image*? Or something entirely different? And what kept you from doing it with multiple pages after you achieved it with a single page?

Comment: What code did you use? Please edit your question to include it. What PDFBox version? If you used the viewer from 1.8, then press "+" or "-" to change pages. However you should use the viewer from 2.*, that one is easier to use.